# Custom http headers with JsonRest Store (dojo)

Tags: ajax, json, dojo, http-headers, store

I was wondering if there's any way to set my own custom http headers in the Get ajax request (xhr.get) that automatically does a JsonRest store.

There's a related topic but without a great solution:
[Dojo Data grid with custom HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699536/dojo-data-grid-with-custom-http-headers)

I've seen the JsonRest implementation in 'dojo.store.JsonRest' including the constructor, and it's not obvious if we can do it or not (but I don't think so). Example of JsonRest store in use:

```
var store = new JsonRestStore({target: "/Table/" });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would accomplish it subclassing `dojo.store.JsonRest` as you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/kXGzs/).

A. Subclass `dojo.store.JsonRest`:

```
var MyJsonRest = declare(JsonRest, {

    get: function(id, options) {
        return this.inherited(
            arguments,
            [id, lang.mixin(this.defaultGetHeaders, options)]
        );
    }
});
```

So you override `get` method calling superclass' `get`, but the second argument `options` (ie. headers) will now contain also properties from `this.defaultGetHeaders`.

B. Define `defaultGetHeaders` in the constructor:

```
var myJsonRest = MyJsonRest({
    target: "/echo/json/",
    defaultGetHeaders: {
        userId: "xyz",
        requestedBy: "abc",
        requestedFrom: "123"            
    }        
});
```

C. Calling `myJsonRest.get()` method you can also overwrite default headers:

```
myJsonRest.get("someId", { requestedFrom: "321"}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);        
});
```

D. Check request headers:

[image]